# Rails/SQL - excluding objects from joined queries

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am writing a Rails app in which users can test themselves using a database of questions. I have tables for Users and Questions. When a question is answered a QuestionAttempt object is created, linked to the User and Question, which has a boolean attribute "correct", storing whether the user got the question right.

I want to allow users to search for questions using the following options:

1. Show questions I have not attempted before (i.e. no QuestionAttempt objects exist for this question/user)
2. Show questions I have not got right before (i.e. no QuestionAttempt objects exist for this question/user with correct == true)

Given that the database is large I need reasonably efficient queries to do this. I have successfully achieved the first of these queries using the following code:

```
Question.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN question_attempts ON question_attempts.question_id = questions.id").where("question_attempts.id IS NULL AND question_attempts.user_id = #{user_id}")
```

This returns all questions with no QuestionAttempt model for the given user. However I can't figure out the necessary query for my second problem, finding all questions with no QuestionAttempt models with correct == true. I have tried the following:

```
Question.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN question_attempts ON question_attempts.question_id = questions.id").where("question_attempts.user_id = #{user_id} AND (question_attempts.correct = 0 OR question_attempts.id IS NULL)")
```

This selects questions which have not been attempted OR have been incorrectly answered. However questions may have been attempted multiple times, with some correct and some incorrect answers - I don't want to return these questions as long as they have at least one correct attempt. How do I exclude these questions from this query?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that there's a limit to the extent to which you should try to force Rails into a different shape to get a good database query, and because the most appropriate SQL syntax for this would be:

```
select ...
from   questions
where  not exists (
         select null
         from   question_attempts
         where  question_attempts.question_id = questions.id and
                question_attempts.user_id     = #{user_id}   and
                question_attempts.correct     = 0)
```

Or to put it in another way, "List the questions for which there is no record of a correct answer for this user.".

Therefore I'd simply write:

```
Question.where("not exists (
                  select null
                  from   question_attempts
                  where  question_attempts.question_id = questions.id and
                         question_attempts.user_id     = #{user_id}   and
                         question_attempts.correct     = 0)")
```

This can be written as a join, but a decent RDBMS query optimiser will convert a not exists to an anti-join anyway, and I think that this syntax is more natural.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I have never been as good with SQL as with Ruby!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I suppose you may use preselect which will get all id's of questions, which were unswered correctly.
You should try

```
question_ids = Question.includes(:question_attempts).where("question_attempts.correct = 1 and questions_attempts.user_id = #{user_id}").pluck(:id) 
Question.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN question_attempts ON question_attempts.question_id = questions.id").where("question_attempts.user_id = #{user_id} AND (question_attempts.id IS NULL OR question.id NOT IN (#{question_ids}))")
```

Comment: It is not very optimized but I like it :)